# How do I configure the ndots option in /etc/resolv.conf from netplan?

Tags: networking, 20.04, dns, netplan, systemd-resolved

I have netplan managing a simple bridge and have DNS served with BIND from the same server, it's all working perfectly well except for relative domain resolution.

`host -t A foo` outputs:

```
foo.example.com has address 192.168.0.3
```

but `host -t A bar.foo` (which is an alias of `foo`) outputs:

```
Host bar.foo not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

even though `ping bar.foo` correctly resolves the domain alias and outputs:

```
PING foo.example.com (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

I think this can be controlled by adding `ndots:2` to the `options` directive in `/etc/resolv.conf` so that the second query is seen as relative, but of course it's not a directly editable file. What's the correct way to pass this configuration on from netplan? Or is there another place this can be specified? I don't want to make `/etc/resolv.conf` a regular file if it can be avoided.

I didn't find anything helpful in the [resolved.conf manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/resolved.conf.html).

`/etc/netplan/00-my-config.yaml`:

```yaml
network:
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
    version: 2
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces:
                - eno1
            addresses:
                - 192.168.0.2/24
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                    - 192.168.0.2
                    - 192.168.0.1
                search:
                    - example.com
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate issues:

- `host -t A bar.foo` explicitly looks for an "A" record for "bar.foo".  Assuming you mean that "bar.foo" is a CNAME for "foo", I think specifying the `-t A` should return NXDOMAIN as there is no A record.
- Netplan.io defers to `system-resolved` for DNS management.  It appears that systemd [explicitly opted to NOT support ndots-like functionality](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4821).  I think this is a moot point as your problem is because of your options to the `host` command as described above.

Comment: Your second point answers my question, but your first point is not correct. if I run `host -t A baz`, I get `baz.example.com is an alias for example.com` then `example.com has address 66.55.44.33`.